# Zabbix graph not showing disk usage

Tags: disk-space-utilization, zabbix

So, I am using Zabbix to monitor my server.
At / file system I have 63 GB free. So I wanted to fake a huge file on that directory to see if the Zabbix graphs would correctly show that the used space had increased. So I ran this :

```
cd / && sudo fallocate -l 50000000000 archivogrande.txt
```

Which is working correctly and creating a file of approximately 50 GB. Unfortunately, Zabbix graph does not get updated. I can still see that there is 63 Gb free when actually it should say 17. The graph is getting updated every 10 seconds by the way.

So, my question is, regardless of what Zabbix might or might not doing wrong here, is my command actually doing what I expected? Would monitoring software correctly see the increase in used space, even if its not a "real" file?

Comment: What does `df -h` say? If you look at the item history in Zabbix, does it get new values?

Comment: @Richlv df -h returns the right size for the file. I did not check the history ill do

Comment: Hmm, `df` is not supposed to show size of a single file usually. Could you please clarify what you are seeing?

Comment: @Richlv yes, i ran df -h and i can see the free available space on the hard drive has decreased as  expected. also, i ran ls-lh and i can see the file being ALMOST 50 gb

Comment: What is the item key your are using? If you query the agent using `zabbix_get` for that key, what is returned?

Comment: when I run zabbix_get I get command not found. And I cant install it through apt because although I added all the necessary repos the package is never found :(

Comment: The package name is zabbix-get, the command name is zabbix_get.
If you still can't find it, add the zabbix repo and it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question - yes `fallocate` command is actually doing what you think it is - you are occupying about ~50 GB of space by the file you created.

Your zabbix-agent binary should be able to detect the space has decreased and alert you that free space is bellow 10% if you're using the correct item and trigger and the monitoring is working OK.

Since this is not the case please verify:

- your agent is sending metrics to the server / server is pulling metrics OK
- your item for free space on rootfs (/) is updated regularly
- you have the correct template selected for the monitored host (I advise https://www.zabbix.org/mw/images/0/04/Template_OS_Linux-4.0.0.xml or newer)

look at the logs of server and agent to figure out what's wrong.